# Still No Luck With Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, pagination

I have asked a similar question but I had no luck in finding an answer.  I think I provided too much information, so this time it's going to be short and sweet.

#### Description

I have a reply form I want to render inside a paginated item.  The paginated item is defined as `@share_item` therefore when I write codes inside that partial they will look like this:

```
<% if registered_member?(share_item.user) %>
```

#### Problem

The problem occurs when I want to render the form partial.  With some code omitted, it looks something

```
<%= form_for(@blob) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, rows: "2", placeholder: "Reply to @#{share_item.user.name}" %>
```

`@blob` is the main model controller where everything is defined, where `@share_item` is a paginated item of `@blob`.  I get the error `share_item is an undefined model or method`.

#### What Works

If I add the form's html directly inside the partial, I can add something like this:

```
<textarea id="blob_content" name="blob[content]" placeholder="Reply to @<%= share_item.user.name %>">@<%= share_item.user.name %> </textarea>
```

and I will receive no errors.

#### What I want

I want to be able to render the form rather than adding the form directly inside the partial (it's annoying, uncanny, and space-consuming).  I have other codes that are similar, and I am basically just looking for a solution on how I can get the same results from rendering a form as adding the HTML to the partial under circumstances as these.

Comment: I think you mean `#{@share_item.user.name}` instead of `@#{share_item.user.name}`, unless I misunderstand your intent.

Comment: Agreed. Is it `@share_item` or `share_item`?

Comment: The @ before the hash symbol is just to allow it to render @member's name... (it's like twitter lol)  I have tried adding "@share_item.user.name" but when I render the form it keeps giving me the undefined local variable error.

Comment: Your question says it's defined as `@share_item`, but both chunks of sample code say it's `share_item`. The snippets currently posted should both fail if your question is correct, or both succeed if it is not.

Comment: Agree with above comments, mainly because the error message you're getting means "I am expecting something that is like a model or method, but share_item isn't one of those".  The @ in your text is just a character, but in the code `@share_item` references an instance variable, so maybe you want `"Reply to @<%= @share_item.user.name %>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <%= form_for(@blob) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content, rows: "2", placeholder: "Reply to @<%= @share_item.user.name%>" %>
```